# Powering ESP32 and two MG90S using supercapacitor

Tags: capacitor, batteries, supercapacitor, drone

I'm working on a drone-dart project.

[image]

Dart is controlled by an ESP32CAM and two MG90S servo motors. It is raised to the sky by a drone and then released. The dart falls while attempting to aim itself into a target laying on the ground (basically a cross) while doing some computer vision and machine learning as it falls (reminds me of a whale scene from hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy https://youtu.be/BFSst3ujx6U?t=50).

So I was reviewing my power options today and lost several hours trying to figure out what's the best battery to power this build. The batteries I reviewed were either too heavy or too weak or had inappropriate nominal to power this build. I came to conclusion that I'm moving in a wrong direction. I don't need all that battery capacity. I'm not even able to consume a fraction of it. Dart's life cycle is 3-5 minutes tops (assuming some power is needed for ESP32 to function before it is released).

A maximum power consumption for this build is 800 ma * 2 servos + 600 ma is 2200 ma at 5 to 6 volts. To simplify calculations lets assume the dart consumes maximum power during all of its life cycle.

So this means I don't need a battery. I need a supercapacitor? Or do I need it? I have literally zero experience with supercapacitors as I never used one before. How big of a capacitor do I need? Maybe a combination of battery + supercapacitor? Or my line of thinking is totally wrong here? Am I missing anything? Any thoughts, ideas? How would you organize power for such build?

Comment: You want a few amps at a few volts, so basically a cell phone or flashlight battery.  Given the low energy density, a super capacitor would be at least an order of magnitude larger and tremendously more expensive.

Comment: I think I would use a 9V Lithium (non chargeable) Energizer battery with a buck converter. It has very much power, more than enough.

Comment: Crucial: What is your desired power source size and mass?

Comment: Well this build is already 300+ grams, while I was planning for it to be somewhere in 100 grams territory. Adding a battery that is worth 50 grams of weight introduces a challenge at a later point in time. As for the size I'm more or less flexible here C or D batteries would fit but the weight is the kicker here. Also the price is the issue, I'm not ready to buy 50$ battery for a 20$ build @RussellMcMahon

Comment: Where are you located. LTO (Lithium Titanium Oxide) batteries should get you excited :-). Example only, [this one](https://www.batteryspace.com/LTO-1865-Rechargeable-Cell-2.4V-1100-mAh-30A-rated-2.64Wh-2.aspx) is  sold in the US for $9.95, 480 mAh, 7.5A max continuous, 10 grams (!!!?), -20C to 60C discharging, ... !   [Spec sheet](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/7470.pdf)  ...

Comment: ... 

[This one](https://www.batteryspace.com/LTO-1020-Rechargeable-Cell-2.4V-50-mAh-2.0A-rated-0.12Wh.aspx) is probably just suitable, 50 mAh, 3 grams :-), [spec sheet here](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/7455.pdf)

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'm from Ukraine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary:  Small LTO or LiIon cells (maybe two in series) may meet your requirement but if using LiIon, then to minimise size and mass you may need to be prepared to use devices outside their ratings. This is doable in some cases - finding which products allow this is liable to be a "try it and see" process. LTO are available well within your specification.

Use of a boost or buck converter would make battery choice more flexible.

---

That's a substantial amount of energy.

E = P x t = V x I x t joule
= 5V x 1A average (say) x 300 seconds = 1500 joule.

A 1F capacitor at 5V has a TOTAL energy content of 1/2 x C x V^2
= 0.5 x 1F x 25 = 12.5 joule.
So you'd need 1500/12.5 = 120F if the TOTAL energy was used.

If Vcap fall of  from 6V to 4V say was tolerable then energy per Farad is
0.5 x 1 x (6^2 - 4^2) = 10 joule.

So you'd need 6V x 150F of capacitor.
That is expensive and probably larger and heavier than a battery.
A 5V battery needs 1500/5V = 300 seconds operation at 1A
= I x t/3600 = 0.085 Ah.
= Tiny.

---

**LTO - Lithium Titanium Oxide):**

LTO (Lithium Titanium Oxide) batteries should get you excited :-) - very high charge and discharge rates and excellent cycle life.

Example only, [this one](https://www.batteryspace.com/LTO-1865-Rechargeable-Cell-2.4V-1100-mAh-30A-rated-2.64Wh-2.aspx) is  sold in the US for $9.95, 480 mAh, 7.5A max continuous, 10 grams (!!!?), -20C to 60C discharging, ... !   [Spec sheet](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/7470.pdf)  ...

---

**LiIon / LiPO:**   If you can tolerate a single LiIon / LiPo cell you can get them in a wide range of capacities. A single cell has a voltage of from 3V to 4.2V. Two in series give a 6 - 8.4V range and even a linearc regulator would be acceptable in this application.
[Here](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/smallest-rechargeable-battery.html) are a range of LiIon/LiPo cells for sale on Alibaba - buyer beware as ever. Discharge rates may be lower than you need - be sure to check if adequate. If at least a specification page is not available they would be safer avoided.
This 40 mAh LiPo datasheet from Sparkfun shows a 1C = 40 mA maximum discharge rate - obviously very unisuited to your task - others may have very much higher maximum rates.

[Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32795863154.html) as an **example only** is a 1000 mAh with a claimed 1C = 1A maximum discharge rate and 500 mA continuous rate. Cells like this MAY tolerate occasional 2C discharge, and may not. In applications like this a small amount of rocket science may be in order.

---

A "PP3" 9V Alkaline battery with a as large as practical electrolytic capacitor **may** work.
This is outside their normal usage range and no specification sheets cover this area.

Some 7.2 V LiIon camera batteries of lowest available mAh should work well.

What is your target size and mass?

E&OE :-)

Comment: This is probably obvious but `l x t` is `labour x time`, correct? 0.085Ah is exactly my point I'm not using even slight percentage of all the power stored in battery. The problem with LTO batteries are that you would need two of those to get the necessary voltage (which is 9$ from china) or to use voltage regulator. Both of these options introduce dilemma in terms of flexibility / reliability. I also encountered Lithium Iron Phosphate to be little cheaper. An alternative to those would be non rechargeable CR2 batteries which come for 1.17$ per pair. Not sure about their weight though.

Comment: Target size is less of an issue internal body diameter is 45 mm. Height is "the lower the better" but upper limit is 50-80 mm. Weight is the most demanding aspect in this puzzle. I would prefer a final solution to be under 20-30 g. The higher the mass the less time the drone will be able to work

Comment: @Lu4 LTO (Lithium Titanium Oxide cells are looking quit reasonable. It's not so much their energy density, which is lower than liIon, but their high relative discharge rates, which means you can get high currents or a small cell/battery.  A boost conveter is almost certainly a viable option. It gives you a steady Vout  and allows low battery voltage and variable battery voltage. . || You can get LTO very cheap from Asia and at reasonable cost in the US. Where are you located?

Comment: @Lu4  i = current. t = time. i x t = amp-seconds (or amp-hours)

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate different types of energy storage, a Ragone plot is useful like:

[image: Ragone Plot]

from: S. J. Moura, J. B. Siegel, D. J. Siegel, H. K. Fathy and A. G. Stefanopoulou, "Education on vehicle electrification: Battery Systems, Fuel Cells, and Hydrogen," 2010 IEEE Vehicle Power and Propulsion Conference, 2010

Your 5 min duration is pretty close to the 0.1 hr line, which lies below batteries and way above super capacitors.  The closest solution is the battery, and as it is above your line then to get the power you want you will end up with more energy (longer run time) than you need.  The super caps have a much lower energy density so will weigh much more to get your 5 min runtime.

Note that these generic plots are just that and have a definite scale in mind (particularly WRT ICE and flywheels), but the comparison between batteries and capacitors is reasonably general.  You should plot your proposed solutions to check that the comparisons are appropriate at your scale.